# Estimation of ATT and average untreated effect on the untreated by OLS estimation

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model, treatment-effect, treatment

Suppose there are a binary treatment.

Based on the treatment, we can consider a treatment group and a control group.

Here, assume the following data generating process of potential outcomes:
\begin{align*}Y_{id}^1&=\alpha_d+Y_{id}^0 \\
Y_{id}^0&=u_{id},\end{align*}
where $i$ is the individual index, $d$ is the group index ($d=1$ indicates the treatment group and $d=0$ means the other group).

For example, $Y_{i1}^1$ is the potential "treated" outcome of an individual in the treatment group.

In this setup, our parameters of interest are
\begin{align}\mathbb{E}&[Y^1-Y^0|d=1]=\alpha_1 \\
\mathbb{E}&[Y^0-Y^1|d=0]=-\alpha_0.\end{align}

That is, we want to identify and estimate the average treatment effect on the treated (ATT) and the average untreated effect on the untreated.

We can identify the parameters separately:

because $Y_{id}=Y_{id}^0+(Y_{id}^1-Y_{id}^0)D_i$ (where $D_i=1$ if $i$ is treated and $D_i=0$ if $i$ is untreated),

$Y_{i1}=Y_{i1}^0+(Y_{i1}^1-Y_{i1}^0)D_i=Y_{i1}^0+\alpha_1D_i$ and $Y_{i0}=Y_{i0}^0+\alpha_0D_i$.

Therefore, by using the linear model and OLS estimation, we can get $\hat{\alpha_1}$ and $\hat{\alpha_0}$.

**However, I want to estimate $\alpha \equiv (\alpha_1,\;-\alpha_0)$ by just one-stage OLS estimation.**

In my personal opinion, it is impossible because

(i) the two parameters are symmetric in the sense that $\alpha_1$ is an average of $Y^1-Y^0$ and $\alpha_0$  is an average of $Y_0-Y_1$. **(but, a linear model with a dummy cannot estimate both of them simultaneously)**

(ii) the intercept term in $Y_{id}=Y_{id}^0+\alpha_d D_i+\epsilon_i$ hinder to estimate just the parameters of interest.

So, I am wondering how we can estimate the parameter of interest by one-shot OLS.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, we usually need at least $k$ equations/observations in order to obtain estimators for $k$ parameters. In this case, you have two parameters ($\alpha_{0,1}$). While some kind of reparameterization could be somehow found (usually these are freshman's calculus tricks), the solution would be coupled.

Even more generally - how could you infer anything about a difference between two groups if you only have a single sample, belonging to one of them?

To the best of my knowledge, the One-Shot terminology sometimes refer to a small sample (but not necessarily $n=1$). If this is the case ($n>1$), you could try and fit an ANOVA model (which is OLS and fits the general problem setting).

Comment: I made some confusion. the term one-shot is used to refer one-stage. I am sorry about the confusing part.